# Repeating a column's value multiple times in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm half-way through the code just need help to create final table. As of now I've achieved below:

```
          0   1
0     exam7  61
1     exam9  38
2     exam3  85
3     exam7  70
4     exam5  44
..      ...  ..
579   exam4  60
580  exam10  48
581   exam4  55
582   exam7  75
583   exam8  82
```

And I need final output as:

```
StudentID,Exam,Score
1,exam7,61
1,exam9,38
1,exam3,85
1,exam7,70
1,exam5,44
1,exam10,43
1,exam1,68
2,exam2,66
2,exam2,69
2,exam8,85
2,exam6,62
2,exam3,92
2,exam8,72
2,exam5,44
2,exam4,50
2,exam9,23
3,exam7,68
3,exam6,73
3,exam2,62
3,exam2,72
4,exam10,41
4,exam4,52
4,exam4,52
4,exam1,70
5,exam4,52
5,exam4,45
5,exam4,61
6,exam10,39
6,exam4,55
6,exam2,67
6,exam4,50
6,exam9,37
.......
95,exam8,79
95,exam3,84
95,exam3,89
95,exam8,80
96,exam10,47
96,exam4,53
96,exam6,64
96,exam6,57
96,exam2,71
96,exam1,79
96,exam8,77
96,exam2,56
97,exam1,72
97,exam8,83
98,exam3,83
98,exam5,55
98,exam6,71
99,exam3,87
99,exam9,34
99,exam3,84
99,exam8,75
99,exam3,80
99,exam4,60
99,exam10,48
99,exam4,55
99,exam7,75
100,exam8,82
```

My Code:

```
pairs = df['Exams'].str.split(', ').sum()
    pairs = [p.split(' ')[0] for p in pairs] 
    #Fetching all 'scores'
    score = df['Scores'].str.split(', ').sum()
    score = [i for i in score]
    data=list(zip(pairs,score))

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df1)
```

I need to add Student ID multiple times for each row. My data in csv is as follows:

```
1   Rodriguez, Pamela   graduate    exam7 (2017), exam9 (2018), exam3 (2018), exam7 (2017), exam5 (2020), exam10 (2019), exam1 (2016)   61, 38, 85, 70, 44, 43, 68
2   Jackson, Kristie    undergraduate   exam2 (2017), exam2 (2017), exam8 (2018), exam6 (2017), exam3 (2018), exam8 (2018), exam5 (2020), exam4 (2019), exam9 (2018)    66, 69, 85, 62, 92, 72, 44, 50, 23
3   Curtis, George  graduate    exam7 (2017), exam6 (2017), exam2 (2017), exam2 (2017)  68, 73, 62, 72
```

Please let me know if you can help me with this. I've zipped the last two columns and put it in my DF but this Student ID column is crazy.

Edit:
So the StudentID is unique for each row. But now I'm splitting my 1 row of exam, score into multiple rows. Check my data where row 1 is as follows:

"Rodriguez, Pamela   graduate    exam7 (2017), exam9 (2018), exam3 (2018), exam7 (2017), exam5 (2020), exam10 (2019), exam1 (2016)   61, 38, 85, 70, 44, 43, 68"
Rodriguez, Pamela   graduate: Last_name,First_name,Program
Exams (year) and Scores are 'comma' separated and in single row only.
I want them to be in different rows. So, I basically want to iterate through each row of the data and fetch all exams and corresponding marks for studentID 1,2,3 and so on and then store it in a new dataframe.

Comment: Your code is a little tricky to follow... could you [edit] to describe how the StudentID's are supposed to be derived for the output?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your initial dataframe, you can extract the data while keeping the index per student:

```
df2 = (df['Scores'].str.split(',\s*')
        .rename('Scores').explode().to_frame()
        .join(df['Exams'].str.extractall('(?P<Exam>exam\d+)').droplevel(1))
        )
```

Output:

```
   Scores   Exam
1      61  exam7
1      61  exam9
1      61  exam3
1      61  exam7
1      61  exam5
..    ...    ...
3      62  exam2
3      72  exam7
3      72  exam6
3      72  exam2
3      72  exam2
```

Comment: I just ran your code and I got something different:   
0      61   exam7
0      61   exam9
0      61   exam3
0      61   exam7
0      61   exam5
..    ...     ...
98     75   exam4
98     75  exam10
98     75   exam4
98     75   exam7
99     82   exam8